# Design for a checkers program

Tags: c++, oop

I'm working on a game of checkers, and I'm getting to the "actually implement the game" part that comes after the "get things rendering" part. Currently I have the logic for my pieces going like this:

```
struct Square {
    Piece * piece;
}

struct Piece {
    bool king;
    Color color;
}
```

with methods for rendering and stuff like that. The idea behind that is that a square can be empty sometimes, and in those cases, the pointer in the square can be null. But, the idea of a struct just to hold a pointer bothers me. My question is whether or not this is a good idea, or if I'm being an idiot and overcomplicating things.

Comment: Well it's one way to do it. However, it's probably more common to have a `Board` struct which contains an 8x8 array of `Piece*` (although if I were doing it, I wouldn't be using pointers).

Comment: It depends on if you plan to extend your checker squares to have additional properties. Like, traps. "Aha! You have activated my trap card, 'king demotion'!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. It's not really necessary to uniquely identify and track each piece in a game of checkers; simply knowing that a piece exists at a given square is probably sufficient. Thus:

```
enum CheckersPiece {
    SQUARE_EMPTY       = 0,
    SQUARE_BLACK_PIECE = 1,
    SQUARE_BLACK_KING  = 2,
    SQUARE_RED_PIECE   = -1,
    SQUARE_RED_KING    = -2,
};

enum CheckersPiece board[8][4];
```

The values in the enum are chosen specifically such that you can check the sign of a value to determine piece color, and the absolute value to check its type.

Note that the board is 8x4 rather than 8x8 because only four squares are usable for pieces on each row of the board. (You could make it 8x8, but then you'd have to be careful to only ever use the "valid" positions.)

Comment: I would use an [8][8] though.  [8][4] saves memory, but is overcomplicated.  And you're only wasting 24 bytes of memory.  Function call overhead is probably more than that.

Comment: I think I'd go for something half way this answer and the original question. Maybe an `optional<Piece> board[8][8];` where `Piece` stores the colour and whether it is a king or not. Then I'd wrap it in a class which exposes a simple `move` function. Just another way of representing the problem. Yours is more focussed on optimisation.

Comment: The reason I thought of this system in the first place was to add some variations in the board, like variable sizes, or holes in the center of it or that kind of thing. Is there some kind of elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For this case, I would recommend writing a CheckersBoard class like this:

```
enum PieceType // similar to duskwuff's approach
{
    PIECE_TYPE_EMPTY,
    PIECE_TYPE_BLACK_PIECE,
    PIECE_TYPE_BLACK_KING,
    PIECE_TYPE_RED_PIECE,
    PIECE_TYPE_RED_KING
};

class CheckersBoard
{
private:
    // data
public:
    CheckersBoard(int sizeX, int sizeY);
    bool isSquareOccupied(int x, int y);
    PieceType getPieceTypeAt(int x, int y);
    movePiece(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY);
};
```

Now this sure is overcomplicated in comparison to duskwuff's approach. But it allows for adding variation by adding new functionality to `CheckersBoard`, `Piece` and the class responsible for gameplay (which could implement a `GameMode` interface, for example). The `movePiece(...)` function should take care of valid movement. That's useful if some squares must not be moved to. Also, this usually allows you to easily change how `CheckersBoard` holds its data.

Of course, if you plan on bringing in some new stuff, you can split up `PieceType` into separate enums (e.g., PieceType and PieceColor) to easily add more types later. In that case, I would add a struct called `Piece`, containing information like that and let `CheckersBoard` hold pointers to `Piece`s:

```
enum PieceType
{
    PIECE_TYPE_PIECE,
    PIECE_TYPE_KING,
    PIECE_TYPE_GODZILLA,
    PIECE_TYPE_DOUBLE_RAINBOW
};

enum PieceColor
{
    PIECE_COLOR_BLACK,
    PIECE_COLOR_RED
};

struct Piece
{
    PieceType type;
    PieceColor color;
    int turnsUntilSelfDestruction;
    bool isFloating;
};

...
const Piece* getPieceAt(int x, int y);
...
```

In the end, it's a matter of opinion and available resources.